# What's the pythonic idiom for making a simple list out of a list of instances?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, list-comprehension

I have a list of record instances returned by SQLAlchemy.

While the instances have many attributes, I want a new list with only one of the attributes. The java coder in me says:

```
my_records = query.all()
names = []
for my_record in my_records:
    names.append(my_record.name)
```

...which works, of course.  But What's the Pythonic answer? I know there a one-liner that includes these 4 lines into 1, but finding it is like googling for "for".

Comment: Does your dict only have a single value?

Comment: Does names = [r.name for r in query.all()] work?

Comment: No @EdChum, it has many.

Comment: Sorry what I mean is that for each key in your dict is there only a single value rather than say a list of values or a tuple or a dict for each key?

Comment: What type of query is this? If it was a django queryset you can use the `values_list` but I can't tell from your code what `query` is

Comment: The key I care about is a scalar string.

Comment: @jamylak SQLAlchemy query result

Comment: google list comhrepension and the filter function - I use those two in combination often

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are looking for what is called a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
names = [my_record.name for my_record in query.all()]
```

The above is a concise equivalent to the for-loop in your example.

---

In addition, you should be aware that there are [dict comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries):

```
{key:val for key, val in iterable}
```

as well as [set comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets):

```
{item for item in iterable}
```

which will construct new dictionaries and sets respectively.

---

Lastly, all of these constructs allow you to add an optional condition to be tested for each item:

```
[item for item in iterable if condition]
{key:val for key, val in iterable if condition}
{item for item in iterable if condition}
```

This is useful if you want to filter the items from the iterable by the condition.

Comment: yep, that'll do it.  Sorry about the dictionary red-herring.

Answer (score 2):

You want to do a list comprehension:

```
result = [my_record['name'] for my_record in query.all()]
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively to list comprehension you can use [`operator.attrgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.attrgetter) and [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map):

```
map(operator.attrgetter('name'), query.all())
```

(But the list comprehension variant is easier to read IMO.)

Comment: Note that this will return a map object in Python 3.x.  In that version, you will need to call `list()` on the result to have the same effect as the loop in the OP's example.